# iOS subscribe to calendar through EventKit

Tags: eventkit

I want to subscribe to a calendar using `EventKit`. I know how to add one-time or recurring events to the Calendar, but I am having trouble figuring out how to add subscriptions based calendars.

Currently I am using a url scheme:

```
let webcal = URL(string: "webcal://\(url)")!
UIApplication.shared.openURL(webcal)
```

The problem with this however, is that calendars added through URLs do not sync with iCloud.

Is there any way to subscribe to a calendar using `EventKit` instead of opening it through a URL scheme?